# Escaping within nested functions

Tags: python, escaping

I have been searching everywhere and have not figured how to do this. Basically I'm trying to set-up a simple CLI where at any given time within the called functions pressing the escape button will take me back to the menu(). Not sure how complicated this is to perform, as I have tried several solutions/variations posted on these boards, none of which have worked for me. Was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. Greatly appreciated!

The main loop basically calls all the functions and looks like the following:

```
if __name__=='__main__': 
    while True:
        command = raw_input("> ")
        if command.lower() == 'exit':
            quit()
            continue
        elif command.lower() == 'help':
            menu()
            continue
        elif command.lower() == 'show':
            show()
            continue
        elif command.lower() == 'find':
            finder()
            continue
        else:
            print("Not a valid command.")
```

An example would be if I called the finder() function during the loop and I have the following:

```
def finder():
    q = raw_input("Search for q: ")
    for row in open("filename.csv"):
        if q in row:
            print row,
```

Would it be possible to trigger the escape key to take me to another function such as menu() while the input is asking me for q? Ideally I would want the escape code to exist outside the functions instead of creating an argument in every function that already exists inside the main loop. I don't know if there's an easy way to accomplish this.

Comment: Would a `KeyboardInterrupt` suffice? I.e. ctrl-c

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work as It force exits the program. I'm just looking for a way to go back to another function without closing the program completely. But i'm all ears if there's a way to do it with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your call to `finder()` as such:

```
try:
    finder()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

If you press ctrl-c during finder(), this will break out of finder and continue at the point from which it was called.

Also, all of the `continue`s in your conditionals are unnecessary, and can be removed. The `while-loop` will not break unless explicitly told to, or it's condition changes.